# Session.Property in WiX custom actions

Tags: vbscript, wix, installshield

I'm converting an install from InstallShield to WiX. One of the custom actions is a simple VBScript which references

```
Session.Property("SETUPEXEDIR")
```

which in InstallShield represents the location of the setup files. When the script runs via WiX that expression evaluates to an empty string.

How can I get that value inside a VBScript for a Wix custom action?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't.   That value is a public property passed from InstallShield's Setup.exe ( if using one ) to your MSI.  With no setup.exe, you have no property.

The closest property built-in to MSI would be the [OriginalDatabase property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370562%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  You'd use Session.Property["OriginalDatabase"] to get the value that parse it in VBScript to get the directory.